# Is there a way to make ESP32 discoverable as a Bluetooth device on a Flutter iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am developing a Flutter application needs to communicates with an ESP32 device via Bluetooth Serial. I have implemented Bluetooth functionality on Android using the FlutterBlue library. However, I'm facing difficulties making the ESP32 discoverable as a Bluetooth device on iOS.

Is there a Flutter library or a workaround that allows me to make it work on the Flutter iOS app?

I need a solution that works for both Android and iOS platforms.

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to achieve this. Thank you!

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. I integrated the FlutterBlue library into my Flutter project and followed the necessary steps to enable Bluetooth functionality.
2. I ensured that the app has the necessary permissions for Bluetooth and location access on Android and iOS.
3. I tested the app on an iOS device, but it does not detect the ESP32 device in the list of available Bluetooth devices, although the BLE devices appear.
4. I expected the app to detect and display the ESP32 device as it does on Android. However, on iOS, the ESP32 device is not discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not support SPP (Bluetooth Serial). You will need to use BLE if you want to communicate to both Android and iOS with the same protocol.

FlutterBlue supports BLE, so you should be able to use that, just not over serial. [The docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) include the information you need to set it up on iOS. For setting up a GATT Server (which is what BLE primarily uses) on ESP32, see the [GATT Server API](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/bluetooth/esp_gatts.html) docs. This will replace your use of SPP.